# Iterate the items of multi-hierarchical list that includes nested dictionaries and print it to csv in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fetch multi-hierarchical list which also have sub-dictionaries and write it to csv with headers.
My json looks like:-

```
"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "xyz": 1,
    "abc": "pqr",
    "mmi": null
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "pt",
    "coordinates": [
      -118.8957,
      38.8607,
      5.3
    ]
  },
  "id": "abc101"
},
```

Which should give below output,
[image]
The hierarchy shown in the image of the output is what exactly I am trying to get, but have'nt find any proper solution for that.

Thank you for any help on the above, in advance.

Comment: what have you tried yet, can you share a [minimum verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) json.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of all columns which are not hierarchical (not `.` in columns names) and last [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns by `.` for `MultiIndex`:

```
a = {"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "xyz": 1,
    "abc": "pqr",
    "mmi": 'null'
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "pt",
    "coordinates": [
      -118.8957,
      38.8607,
      5.3
    ]
  },
  "id": "abc101"
},{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "xyz": 1,
    "abc": "pqr",
    "mmi": 'null'
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "pt",
    "coordinates": [
      -118.8957,
      38.8607,
      5.3
    ]
  },
  "id": "abc101"
}]}
```

---

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(a['features']).set_index(['id','type'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)
                                 geometry      properties          
                              coordinates type        abc   mmi xyz
id     type                                                        
abc101 Feature  [-118.8957, 38.8607, 5.3]   pt        pqr  null   1
       Feature  [-118.8957, 38.8607, 5.3]   pt        pqr  null   1
```

EDIT:

If want read again `file` with `MultiIndex`, better is not remove first repeating column:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1])
print (df)
                                 geometry      properties        
                              coordinates type        abc mmi xyz
id     type                                                      
abc101 Feature  [-118.8957, 38.8607, 5.3]   pt        pqr NaN   1
       Feature  [-118.8957, 38.8607, 5.3]   pt        pqr NaN   1
```

But if really need it:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(a['features']).set_index(['id','type'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

s = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
s1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
s0 = np.where(s.duplicated(),'',s)
df.columns = [s0, s1]

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael!! :) There is still one concern where the headers appear on above each column where as I want only one header appearing above group of columns that fall under that header. Is there any way out of that?

Comment: @MedhaTrivedi - Do you think in output file?

Comment: yes. When I write it down to csv it writes "properties" as header above every column("abc", "xyz", "mmi"), that means 3 times.